# how to get content of webpage designed in asp.net using php?

Tags: php

```
<?php       
$url='http://www.cfp.net/find/EnhancedSearch.aspx';
$s = @file_get_contents($url);  
    if (empty($s))
    {
    // Web page empty/access failure
        echo "sorry!";
    }
    else
    {
    echo($s);
}
?>
```

------i tried with htmlextension page it works and also work for "http://www.cfp.net" but it shows error message as sorry that means $s is empty why $s is not getting any content in above code.

Please help me get content of http://www.cfp.net/find/EnhancedSearch.aspx in variable $s and save the content in html page i.e with extension html using pure php code.

Comment: Why do you suppress warnings for `file_get_contents()`? If you remove the `@`, does it give a warning?

Comment: Yep, it will give HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error :)

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is to do with not overriding the default user agent for the request.

The server is rejecting PHPs default user agent.

For some reason it accepts a wget request but not a PHP request by default - strange.

If you change it to a spoofed browser user agent then the request works.

Heres the full code:

```
$opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
                'method'=>"GET",
                'user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6',
        )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$url='http://www.cfp.net/find/EnhancedSearch.aspx';

$s = file_get_contents($url,false,$context); 

    if (empty($s))
    {
    // Web page empty/access failure
        echo "sorry!";
    }
    else
    {
    echo($s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advice you to check out this on the server..

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   CertificantSearch.CFP.get_bMobile() in D:\2.0Projects\CFPBoard\Certificant\CertificantSearch\CFP.Master.cs:23
   CertificantSearch.EnhancedSearch.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in D:\2.0Projects\CFPBoard\Certificant\CertificantSearch\EnhancedSearch.aspx.cs:151
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +99
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +50
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +627
```

Since this gives internal error and since you suppress errors on top, it even can't report any errors. And I'd advice using CURL

Comment: With CURL - it receives response body, not only 500 error headers

Comment: Ah yes I see. With the original file_get_contents code it just halts with "HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error"